# How do I find the source file with the most lines of code in a git repository?

Tags: git

How do I find the source file with the most lines of code in a git repository? I'm looking for a quick command/way to achieve this.

Comment: Is Python out of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this is what I ended up with (for Java source):

find . -name '*.java' -type f | grep -v "generated" | grep -v "/test/" | xargs wc -l | sort -nr